# Executing a stored procedure with custom types gives null result

Tags: java, plsql, spring-jdbc

I have written java code for the below plsql code to execute stored procedure. I am not getting result when I run the procedure from Java code.

PLSQL

```
declare
    CAMFORMLIST_ID_TY CAMFORMLIST_ID_TYPES;
    CAMFORMLIST_ID_T CAMFORMLIST_ID_TYPE;
    OFEERS_INFO_TY OFEERS_INFO_TYPE;

begin
    CAMFORMLIST_ID_T:=CAMFORMLIST_ID_TYPE('HH','K');
    CAMFORMLIST_ID_TY:=CAMFORMLIST_ID_TYPES(CAMFORMLIST_ID_T);

    GETOFEERSFROMCAMFORM(CAMFORMLIST_ID_TY,OFEERS_INFO_TY);

    for i in OFEERS_INFO_TY.FIRST..OFEERS_INFO_TY.LAST loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: '|| OFEERS_INFO_TY(i).OFFER_NAME);
    end loop;
end;
```

My Java  Stored Procedure class.

```
@Component
public class GetOffersFromCAMFORM extends StoredProcedure {
  private static final String OFEERS_LIST = "Offers";

  @Autowired
  private String MySchema;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("MyDataSource")
  private DataSource dataSourceMy;

  @PostConstruct
  public void postConstruct() {
    this.setDataSource(dataSourceMy);
    this.setSql(MySchema + ".getOffersFromCAMFORM");

    declareParameter(new SqlParameter(SUB_FORM, Types.ARRAY, MySchema + ".CAMFORMLIST_ID_TYPES"));
    declareParameter(
        new SqlOutParameter(OFEERS_LIST, OracleTypes.ARRAY,
        MySchema + ".OFEERS_INFO_TYPE", new ReturnType()));
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<MyOffer> execute(final String subscriptionForm, final String subscriptionClass)
      throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    objects.put(SUB_FORM, new AbstractSqlTypeValue() {
      @Override
      protected Object createTypeValue(Connection con, int SqlType, String typeName)
          throws SQLException {

        OracleConnection oracle =
            (OracleConnection) (new DelegatingConnection(con)).getInnermostDelegate();
        if (oracle != null) {
          con = oracle;
        }

        ArrayList<Struct> CAMFORMListIdType = new ArrayList<Struct>();

        CAMFORMListIdType
            .add(((OracleConnection) con).createStruct(MySchema + ".CAMFORMLIST_ID_TYPE",
                new String[] {subscriptionForm, subscriptionClass}));

        return ((OracleConnection) con).createARRAY(MySchema + ".CAMFORMLIST_ID_TYPES",
            CAMFORMListIdType.toArray(new Struct[] {}));
      }
    });

    Map<?, ?> result = execute(objects);

    List<MyOffer> items = (List<MyOffer>) result.get(OFEERS_LIST);
    return items;
  }

}
```

Return type

```
public class ReturnType implements SqlReturnType {


  @Override
  public List<PCOffer> getTypeValue(CallableStatement cs, int colIndx, int sqlType,
      String typeName) throws SQLException {

    Array dba = (Array) cs.getObject(colIndx);
    if (dba == null || ((Object[]) dba.getArray()).length == 0) {
      return null;
    }



    ...


    }
```

Ojdbc 7 driver is used.

I am not getting the output. When I execute the procueudre, I get empty array in ReturnType class.

Am I doing something wrong.